# Join issue: Unknown record property / related component

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to join two tables, but having an error:

```
Unknown record property / related component "price" on "Item"
```

This is my DQL:

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('i.id, i.product_id, p.price')
        ->from('Item i')
        ->innerJoin('i.priceItem p')
        ->where('i.id = ?', $request->getParameter('id'))
        ->andWhere('p.currency_code = ?', $request->getParameter('currency_code'));

    $this->item = $q->execute();

    foreach($this->item as $item) {

        var_dump($item->getId());
        var_dump($item->getProductId());
        var_dump($item->getPrice()); // This line is causing the error

    }
```

and schema:

```
Item:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    product_id: { type: string(255), notnull: true }

Price:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    currency_code: { type: string(3), notnull: true }
    item_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    price:  { type: float, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Item: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: item_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: priceItem }
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below `var_dump($item->Price->getPrice());`

`getPrice()` is property of the Price doctrine base class not a Item Class

Comment: Unknown record property / related component "Price" on "Item"

Comment: @RomanNewaza var_dump($item->priceItem->getPrice()); try this

Comment: $item->priceItem is an Array. I can print something referring to its index: $item->priceItem[0]->getPrice(). If I loop it, all the values printed for one row of Item. Should be just one row because of p.currency_code in WHERE, right?

Comment: Instead of using Innerjoin try with leftJoin in your price table

Comment: INNER JOIN returns matched rows only so it should be used. Also, tried leftJoin - same thing. I would surprise if it return one record

Comment: relations:
    Item: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: item_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: priceItem }

here your foreign: product_id and build the schema

Comment: In your schema u have given i cant see any column name like id its product_id see ur question Item:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    product_id: { type: string(255), notnull: true }

Comment: define your primary keys in schema also

Comment: every table has PK automatically.

Answer (score 0):

*price* is a property/field of *Price* object, not *Item*. *Item* is related to *Price* through alias *priceItem*. Then:

```
$item->priceItem['price']
```

More info can be found [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/working-with-models/en#dealing-with-relations%3aretrieving-related-records).

Comment: It returns multiple prices now as it were right join - should be one row

Comment: Try adding *type* and *foreignType* attribute your schema.

relations:
    Item: { onDelete: CASCADE, type: one, foreignType : one, local: item_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: priceItem }

Comment: Now I have one row for Price, but wrong one - it always brings me the first row no matter what currency_code was chosen. And SQL is correct - I monitor mysql.log for queries.

Comment: Try setting manually primary keys:
    item_id: { type: integer, notnull: true, primary: true }
    currency_code: { type: string(3), notnull: true, primary: true }